# Add More and Email Send?

Tags: javascript, email

I currently have code which is the following... take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/DzWD7/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
    var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++) {
        var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;
                break;
        }
    }
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount=table.rows.length;
            for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                var row=table.rows[i];
                var chkbox=row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
                if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount<=1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now when i want to send this form you'll see i can add more Table Rows which in return allow for more lines of code but mainly for its purpose of listing information as many as the user wants.

Now i have to submit this and email this form to an email which i have set up however it only ever pics the first one up, and nothing else, just pick anymore up than the first one, does anyone have a solution for the PHP code for sending it via email?

Comment: Give them names like `credit_type[]` instead of `credit_type` and PHP will pick up all the different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "name" of all the form fields to "name[]". Then PHP will take it as an array. I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/QSG7n/

```
<select class="styled-select" name="credit_type">
```

will become

```
<select class="styled-select" name="credit_type[]">
```

...

```
<input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_production" placeholder="Production"/>
```

will become

```
<input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_production[]" placeholder="Production"/>
```

and so on...

in `PHP` `$_REQUEST['credit_type']` will be an array

```
$count = count($_REQUEST['credit_type']);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo $_REQUEST['credit_type'][$i] . "<br/>";
    echo $_REQUEST['credit_production'][$i] . "<br/>";
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I've done that however I'm getting the word 'Array' where the result is suppose to be shown?

Comment: I have results, that are emailed currently this is what is stated in the PHP File:

$credit_type = $_POST['credit_type[]'];
$credit_production = $_POST['credit_production[]'];
$credit_role = $_POST['credit_role[]'];
$credit_director = $_POST['credit_director[]'];
$credit_company = $_POST['credit_company[]'];

I then view it in a table via email:

<table class="forms">
<tr><td>Type</td><td>Production</td><td>Role</td><td>Director</td><td>Company</td></tr>
<tr><td>$credit_type</td><td>$credit_production</td><td>$credit_role</td><td>$credit_director</td><td>$credit_company</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: No this way. You should have a loop and inside the loop you have to access the array using $_POST['credit_type'][1], $_POST['credit_type'][2] etc;

Comment: @Shajith Nair i apologise this doesn't make sense as it won't go with the PHP code I've already created (pretty new to php) I've done a lot but not enough to understand fully this, I've looked on the internet so i wouldn't have to bother you again but thats not gonna happen sorry, please can you elaborate I'm using EOD I'm basically collecting this information from website page and then sending the results to an email

Comment: Can anyone help I've got the code working, but now i need to put it within an EOD and I've tried putting it into a table in EOD in the send page i have set up, anyone know what i need to do to make that work?